# Expanding active contours opencv - snakeimage

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am doing some image processing that requires me to use active contours to find some edge. The required output is seen in this image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS7sw.png]

what I have is this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOo4x.png]

I thought I could use opencv snakeImage but this is legacy now, and I dont know how to implement this old code. There is also very little documentation and no examples. This makes the problem very hard for me.

Are there any other techniques that would be useful in this situation? I am very stuck.